# How to Access Data By Promise chaining (Node-fetch)

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I want to access the user object(contains attributes like name, age, gender) returned from the second fetch but whenever I do so I get an unexpected object. I get a 200 response so I don't know what I'm missing. steps:

1. Get the token when the user signs in
2. Use the token to login and retrieve the user's data.

   ```
   const fetch = require('node-fetch');


    fetch('http://34.245.86.200:9084/api/auth/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            Identifier: '17123456788',
            Password: 'bambam'
        }),
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json()
    }).then(
        data => {
            const header = {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + data.token
            }

            return fetch('http://34.245.86.200:9085/api/user', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: header
            })
        }).then(msg => {
        console.log(msg.body)
    })
   ```

**Expected response:**

```json
{
    "title": null,
    "firstName": "Kay",
    "lastName": "Atom",
    "primaryPhoneNumber": "+1 712-345-6788",
    "fullName": "Kay Atom",
    "sex": null,
    "email": "kay@bam.com",
    "image": null,
}
```

**Results from Console log in code above:**

```
{
    token:
    'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJrYXlAYmFtLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsIjoia2F5QGJhbS5jb20iLCJnaXZlbl9uYW1lIjoiS2F5Iiwic2lkIjoiMzQ0MDM1ODM5NGZmNGUxNzhkMmJhNzcxNmVjYjM3YTgiLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiJQYXRpZW50IiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoiMDcvMDcvMjAyMCAxNzowOTo1MCIsImV4cCI6MTU5NDE0ODk5MCwiaXNzIjoiTGVpbGFQcm9qZWN0IiwiYXVkIjoiTGVpbGFQcm9qZWN0In0.DHuxUY77Jrsd_wBOrcZ-cmqvE8nh5I3TzpLIrRUuuhI',

    message: 'Successfully Logged In kay@bam.com'
}

PassThrough {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: BufferList {
            head: [Object],
            tail: [Object],
            length: 1
        },
        length: 372,
        pipes: [],
        flowing: null,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        emitClose: true,
        autoDestroy: true,
        destroyed: false,
        errored: false,
        closed: false,
        closeEmitted: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrainWriters: null,
        multiAwaitDrain: false,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype]{
        prefinish: [Function: prefinish],
        unpipe: [Function: onunpipe],
        error: [[Function: onerror], [Function(anonymous)]],
        close: [Function: bound onceWrapper]{
            listener: [Function: onclose]
        },
        finish: [Function: bound onceWrapper]{
            listener: [Function: onfinish]
        }
``
    },
    _eventsCount: 5,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        afterWriteTickInfo: null,
        buffered: [],
        bufferedIndex: 0,
        allBuffers: true,
        allNoop: true,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        emitClose: true,
        autoDestroy: true,
        errored: false,
        closed: false
    },
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _transformState: {
        afterTransform: [Function: bound afterTransform],
        needTransform: true,
        transforming: false,
        writecb: null,
        writechunk: null,
        writeencoding: 'buffer'
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
```

Comment: You are accidentally creating a global variable `header` (you are missing a `const` in front), and I wonder if it is intentional that you are accessing two different ports (9084 the first time, 9085 the second time), but apart from that it looks fine. Can you please add the full error and (if applicable) its stack? What output do you expect to see, what do you see instead? You say "an unexpected object" but it's unclear what that means. Thank you.

Comment: @CherryDT I just edited it to have header defined as a const and got the same response I did before. See edited question for the response I get

Comment: Thank you but you still didn't describe what "unexpected object" you are referring to exactly.

Comment: @CherryDT the object shown after message is the unexpected object. I get a different object(expected) when I test the API on postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.body` refers to a stream of the response. You'll likely want something like `response.json()` or `response.text()`, each which returns a promise.

Comment: Please see above for the expected response

Comment: @idiot, I read your question and this is my attempt at giving you a hint to solve this. You're using `.body` which gives you that stream object. Don't use `.body`, but `.json()`